# Does this require the continuum hypothesis

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\Bbb R$, such that there doesn't exist a surjection from $A$ to $\Bbb R$ and also not from $B$ to $\Bbb R$. I have to prove there doesn't exist a surjection from $A\cup B$ to $\Bbb R$. I have come up with a few methods to prove this, but they all require the continuum hypothesis to be valid.

Does there also exist a proof that does not make use of the continuum hypothesis, or is CH necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - this is provable in ZFC alone. The cardinality of $A\cup B$ is the maximum of the cardinalities of $A$ and $B$ (assuming both $A$ and $B$ are infinite, but that's WLOG).

---

This crucially uses the axiom of choice - it is consistent with ZF that $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as the disjoint union of two sets each of which does not surject onto $\mathbb{R}$.